# React Native App with Expo - QR code not loading

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I'm following this tutorial:

https://blog.expo.io/building-a-react-native-app-using-expo-and-typescript-part-1-a81b6970bb82

`yarn global add create-react-native-app`

`create-react-native-app my-app-name`

`cd my-app-name`

`yarn start`

I am on the same network as my phone (Android). No VPN. I am in the root folder of my app. It says `Loading dependency graph, done.` so I know it's running.

Firewall is also off for this as well and this is not a timeout error.

When I scan the QR code:

`Something went wrong. Could not load exp://10.0.0.21:19000.`

What could be my issue?

**EDIT**

New error: `Uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.21.19000`

Comment: If you are using LAN, make sure your device is on the same wifi network as your development machine. This may not work on some public networks. localhost will not work for iOS unless you are in the simulator, and it only works on Android if your device is connected to your machine via USB.

Comment: Just a couple of other tips. Make sure to verify the link is the same as what's in your configuration file. If so, try to go to it in your browser and pull up network debugging tools. Further network tests are helpful such as tracing and seeing what's going on with the request/responses. I've ran into this before a while ago but was able to resolve just by testing the links either with my browser or curl. Hope that helps.

Comment: @hongdevelop appreciate it. All devices are on the same wifi network. This is on Android. Still not working.

Comment: @jazzmasterkc what endpoint am i using the chrome debugger tools on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try opening the debugger in chrome and then select `tunnel` if your device and the development pc are not connected to the same server.

Answer (score 2):

Try the **Enter URL manually** option

- First make sure you are on the same wifi ( computer || laptop and mobile device)
- Second open cmd and run command **ipconfig** their you will get IPv4 Address ***copy it***
- Go to your ***expo go*** app tap on **Enter URL manually**
- Enter **exp://your_IPv4_Address:19000** ( Example -- exp://192.168.1.38:19000 )
- Connect now -- It should work

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after and expo update. Instead of running

```
npm/yarn start
```

(executes `expo start --dev-client`)

Try

```
npm run run
```

(executes `expo start`)

Answer (score 1):

run the command

```
expo start --tunnel
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used **tunnel**  and there was a problem with the sdk version - I have 39.0.0 and I should use only 36, 37 or 38 - that is the message that i have got from expo, so all I did is to get into the **app.json** file, and add the following line in expo (or just change it if it already exist):

```
"sdkVersion": "38.0.0"
```

and it should look like:

```
    "expo": {
            "name": "DoneWithIt",
            "slug": "DoneWithIt",
            "sdkVersion": "38.0.0",
            "version": "1.0.0",

    ....
    ....
    }
```

In the **package.json** file in dependencies, change the version to 38.0.0 in "expo" and "react-native" :

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~38.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
     38.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  }
```

then run:

```
cd yourAppName 
npm start
```

and it will be loaded on your phone.
you can watch it from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS8VULijAZ4

In this video he uses 32.0.0 so be aware to the updated version (in my case 38.0.0 was good for 09/2020)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `node_modules` folder from your application and then run `npm install` to get the dependencies.

Now run `expo start` or `npm start`, the QR code will load now.

Answer (score 0):

On node v12.18. In the package.json downgrade expo and react-native connector. 38 works instead of 40.

```
"expo": "~38.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Then remove node_modules and reinstall them

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

then run again :

```
npm start
```

QR should work this time

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone is still looking for a solution, just turn off your Firewall, temporarily. In my case, I'm on Windows 11 and McAfee blocks the connections.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  I just did what @Nupur Sharma said, but since the expo cli seems to only now works remotely with npx, I ran the command `npx expo start --tunnel`.  This prompted me to install expo/ngrok which is a server for tunnels and so I accepted. After running the app again I was able to scan the qr code and load the app on my Android device.